# Call to undefined method getConfigurableAttributeCollection()

Tags: magento2, php

When I added Configurable products on the cart then added Simple product on the cart will facing error check screenshot 
[image]

but when we added Simple product on the cart then added Configurable product on the cart after working fine

Comment: DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE user_id = <YOUR_USER_ID>;

Comment: Which user id pass to on query because we are trying to without login

Comment: are you customization on checkout/cart page ?

Comment: Yes, I  have changed only design not functionality.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: All theme files right?

Comment: only theme files to customization for checkout/cart

Comment: can you please give me your email id will share with you

Comment: please to more commet so in personal chat in room by stack exchange.
only share path to which file you used.

Comment: /app/design/frontend/Infortis/ehplabs/Magento_Checkout
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ehplabs/Magento_Catalog

this folder files I have changed

Comment: check in this folder you $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product') this type of code is useing or not ?

Comment: please search in /app/design/frontend/Infortis/ehplabs/Magento_Checkout

Comment: No, I have not using

Comment: please share your phtml file which you have change to your requirements.

Comment: I have set default Magento Luma theme after also not working and we are using the ultimo theme

Comment: anyone, please help me.